# 404 errors on subdirectories after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.xx

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I am receiving a HTTP 404 error when navigating my website's subpages. For example, I can get to www.examplesite.com, but cannot browse to www.examplesite.com/clients or any other subdirectory/page. It used to work, but now it doesn't.

I have verified that the user `www-data` has permissions on `/var/www/` and other subfolders.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem like you in the past, and found out after lot of digging that rewrite module was disabled after upgrade..

Try this,, I hope that it will help you..

enable rewrite

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

also this will help after that,, add this to your .htaccess file in root of domain you are previewing:

```
AllowOverride All
```

hth, cheers, K